# O365 Group Based Licensing not Working

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I have synced our local Active Directory with Azure AD using Azure Connect. I'm trying to assign Office 365 Licensing to Security Groups on Azure Active Directory, but when I clic on "License" inside the group properties, the "Products" tab appear disabled, but for the users the licensing assigment works fine, this only happend with groups.

There some parameter that the Security Groups has to have enabled to be assigned with product licensing? Or do I have to enable something else on Azure Active Directory?

Regards

Comment: `During public preview, a paid or trial subscription for Azure AD Basic or Premium editions is required in the tenant to use group-based license management.` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-licensing-whatis-azure-portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group-based app assignment and licencing requires Azure AD basic or premium licences.